# C++ code to print the number of words in a given string

Tags: c++

This is the link above of the code of printing the number of words.
It's running properly but sometimes it's showing the error "out of range", I don't know the reason,
can someone please explain why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str.at(i) == ' ')
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            while (str.at(i) != ' ')
            {
                i++;
                if (str.at(i) == str.length())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << "number of words are : " << count;
}
```

[Online demo](https://onlinegdb.com/VftVy73Tb)

Comment: What do you mean by `str.at(i) == str.length()`?

Comment: This could give you other ideas: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)

Comment: @ForceBru , If there is no words just spaces till end

Comment: `str.at(i)` is the character at index `i`. Why are you comparing this _character_ with the length of the string? You probably meant to compare `i` itself.

Comment: @ForceBru yeah! I got it now thanks for Explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is:

```
while (str.at(i) != ' ')
```

might go out of bound.

Think what would happen if you enter these lines?

```
Hello!!!!
Hello world!!!
```

It will hit that `while()` loop and loop forever.

Why are you getting error sometimes, and not all the times? Because you are causing undefined behavior.

Your if statement is not doing what you think it is doing. It is comparing characters to `str.lenght()`. So basically you are comparing `H`, `e`, `l`, `l` and `o` against `str.lenght()`.

If we look int ASCII char values we get this:

```
char | decimal value | str.lenght()
-----+---------------+--------------
H    | 72            | 5
e    | 102           | 5
l    | 108           | 5
l    | 108           | 5
o    | 111           | 5
!    | 33            | 5
!    | 33            | 5
!    | 33            | 5
```

Your line:

```
if (str.at(i) == str.length())
    break;
```

should be:

```
if (i == str.length())
    break;
```

to compare position in string with string length. Further more you should never use `==` to check if `i` against `str.lenght()` you should use `>=`, just in case there is a bug in memory somewhere and i skips value of `str.lenght()`.

```
if (i >= str.length())
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the whole loop you are using the expression `str.at(i) == str.length()`, but I believe it should be `I == str.length()`.